# Can you have multiple synonyms for a search term on Magento

Tags: magento

Can you have multiple synonyms for a search term on Magento

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create them one by one in Catalog->Search Terms, but it's possible.